# How to keep Findroot accuracy when the vector equation has additional constraints

Tags: equation-solving, difference-equations

This is a simple example (More complex equations will be considered in actual calculations): I have two vector equations `vx` and `vy`, and I want to keep the third component of `vx` as `0` in the calculation. There are actually 5 unknowns. One clumsy way is to write it in components, but this is not wise once the number of vector equations increases. So I still want to call `Findroot` through vector form, but there is some error in the calculation result. Here is my code:

```
vx0 = {0.6, 0.2, 0};
vy0 = {0.2, 0.3, -Sqrt[1 - 0.2^2 - 0.3^2]};
eps = 0.05;
{vx1, vy1} /. FindRoot[{
   (vx1 - vx0) == 
    eps {(vy1[[2]] + vy0[[2]]), -(vy1[[1]] + vy0[[1]]), 0},
   (vy1 - vy0) == 100 Cross[(vy1 + vy0), (vx1 + vx0)]
   }, {{vx1, vx0}, {vy1, vy0}}, Evaluated -> False]
```

The calculation result of mma `12.0` is (**See `vx1[[3]]` is not zero**):

```
{{0.607551, 0.173064, -1.41475*10^-25}, {0.338711, -0.148987, 
  0.92902}}
```

**I want to directly add `vx1[[3]]==0` in `FindRoot`, but this will cause a mismatch in the number of equations.** (My application scenario is to use the new values of `vx1` and `vy1` as initial values, and continue calling Findroot.Once `vx1[[3]]` has an error, the subsequent errors will accumulate step by step. So I want to solve this problem by considering `vx1[[3]]==0` in the first equation calculation.)

**The strange thing is that in the first equation, the third component has already been set to 0.**

```
(vx1 - vx0) == 
        eps {(vy1[[2]] + vy0[[2]]), -(vy1[[1]] + vy0[[1]]), 0}
```

Is this a problem caused by **machine precision**?

By the way, can I calculate the Jacobi matrix of two vector equations? Similar code like this. (The purpose of calculating Jacobi is to speed up the calculation of findroot. I see that findroot supports input of Jacobi matrix.)

```
eq1 = (vx1 - vx0) - 
   eps {(vy1[[2]] + vy0[[2]]), -(vy1[[1]] + vy0[[1]]), 0};
eq2 = (vy1 - vy0) - 100 Cross[(vy1 + vy0), (vx1 + vx0)];
jacobian = D[{eq1, eq2}, {{vx1, vy1}}]
```

Thank you in advance for your help and comments!

Comment: As compared to the norm of the solution, -1.41475*10^-25 is effectively zero.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yes, this solution is already very small, but if there is always an error, when I iterate through `Nestlist` in a loop, the error will accumulate. So I am considering whether to directly put `vx[[3]]==0` into `Findroot`. I have made some new attempts, such as adding multipliers, which can make the error smaller.

Comment: If you want Mathematica to report it as zero, just use `Chop`.

Comment: Your question makes no mention of NestList. To me at least, it seems that you are not asking about what you really need.

Comment: Maybe you need to read up on floating-point numbers, round-off error, machine epsilon, and error propagation. The ` -1.41475*10^-25` should be a comfort to you, that the code is working correctly. Yet, it seems to have the opposite effect.

Answer (score 1):

Change all your numbers to exact and bump up the `WorkingPrecision` to get it closer.

```
vx0 = {3/5, 1/5, 0};
vy0 = {1/5, 3/10, -Sqrt[1 - (1/5)^2 - (3/10)^2]};
eps = 1/20;
{vx1, vy1} /. FindRoot[{(vx1 - vx0) == 
eps {(vy1[[2]] + vy0[[2]]), -(vy1[[1]] + vy0[[1]]), 0}, (vy1 - 
  vy0) == 100 Cross[(vy1 + vy0), (vx1 + vx0)]}, {{vx1, vx0}, {vy1,
 vy0}}, Evaluated -> False, WorkingPrecision -> 50]//N

(*{{0.607551, 0.173064, -3.35881*10^-98}, {0.338711, -0.148987, 0.92902}}*)
```

With real numbers, you are not going to get exactly zero.

Comment: Thank you, but this method seems to be unstable. For example, my initial value is `vy0 = {0.2, 0.3, -Sqrt[1 - 0.2^2 - 0.3^2]};` MMA will report an error in version 12.0: `The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance`.

Comment: Works fine for me in both v12.0 and v13.2.1.  Try a fresh kernel.

Comment: But you do need to use exact numbers before you can meaningfully increase the `WorkingPrecision`.

Comment: I see, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding Lagrange multipliers, and the output results were slightly better, but still not `vx1[[3]]==0`.

```
vx0 = {0.6, 0.2, 0};
vy0 = {0.2, 0.3, -Sqrt[1 - 0.2^2 - 0.3^2]};
eps = 0.05;
lambda =.;(*Introduce the Lagrange multiplier*)
{vx1, vy1} /. 
 FindRoot[{(vx1 - vx0) == 
    eps {(vy1[[2]] + vy0[[2]]), -(vy1[[1]] + vy0[[1]]), 0}, (vy1 - 
      vy0) == 100 Cross[(vy1 + vy0), (vx1 + vx0)], 
   lambda vx1[[3]] == 
    0 (*Add the constraint using the Lagrange multiplier*)}, {{vx1, 
    vx0}, {vy1, vy0}, {lambda, 1}}, Evaluated -> False]
```

Result is

```
{{0.607551, 0.173064, 6.62808*10^-27}, {0.338711, -0.148987, 
  0.92902}}
```